# What does the Chalice of Blood do?

Tags: deistic-pixel-dungeon

I want to know what does the Chalice of Blood do? And is it worth it?

Note: I am not playing vanilla Pixel Dungeon, but with the mod "Deistic Pixel Dungeon"

Answer (score 1):

It increases your health regeneration. This is definitely worth it if you can survive powering it up.

The Chalice of Blood was introduced in the Shattered Pixel Dungeon mod. Per the [wiki](http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Mod-Shattered_Pixel_Dungeon/Artifacts):

> Abilities:
>   Passively increases health regeneration by reducing your regeneration delay, as long as you are not starving.
>   The default regeneration delay is 10 turns. The Chalice decreases regen delay by (level * 0.9).
>   At +10, the Chalice reduces delay by 9, resulting in a restore rate of 1 HP/turn.
>
> Upgrading:
>   The Chalice is upgraded by using the 'prick' command, which deals damage to the Hero/ine in exchange for an upgrade.
>   This damage is a danger in the short term, but the increase in regen is very helpful in the long term. You don't have to upgrade all at once; wait until you're strong enough to take the damage.

Just to confirm that Deistic Pixel Dungeon did not change this, in the [last update for the mod (0.1.5)](https://www.reddit.com/r/PixelDungeon/comments/3wzvwv/deistic_update_version_015_matthew/), before it went on [hiatus](https://www.reddit.com/r/PixelDungeon/comments/45c1ts/deistic_pixel_dungeon_indefinite_hiatus/), I found the [github repo](https://github.com/BrightBotTeam/DeisticPixelDungeon).

Based on the [ChaliceOfBlood.java](https://github.com/BrightBotTeam/DeisticPixelDungeon/blob/327b24fc5ccf575fd2dda9a6c009895ea4109493/DeisticPixelDungeon/src/com/avmoga/dpixel/items/artifacts/ChaliceOfBlood.java) does not seem to be any different than the same file in the [Shattered Pixel Dungeon repo](https://github.com/00-Evan/shattered-pixel-dungeon/blob/ba8598132aaf5007950ca818f36d850306be7023/core/src/main/java/com/shatteredpixel/shatteredpixeldungeon/items/artifacts/ChaliceOfBlood.java).